# Can I safely append null bytes to a PNG image

Tags: image, png, image-size

I would like to append null bytes to a PNG file to match the previous size. I've successfully added 10 MB to a small image with no issue viewing the image. I am wondering if this is secure based on the definition of the PNG format or if I am just getting lucky from good error correction in software.

Update: I've removed why I want to do this.

Comment: It seems like this is a problem better solved via SVN, rather than padding binary files? See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767481/svn-ignoring-files-already-in-repository or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277258/svn-how-to-make-a-file-read-only-with-subversion, perhaps?

Comment: Subversion doesn't look at the file size, it performs a checksum if the timestamp has changed. So whether you append 1 byte or 10MB, it'll detect a change.

Comment: Most PNG viewers may allow it since there is a clear end-of-file marker, although *technically* "[n]o chunks or other content follow the IEND chunk." (http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#15FileConformance, bullet c).

Comment: Thanks. @Jongware. This site has a serious problem I think with users attempting to close posts, always assuming that I have not done any research and seen the threads in question, maybe trying to get some reputation for it.

Comment: Locks look interesting, but they break the commit. I would rather this post not focus on SVN, as I would get myself booted of the site if I had asked if there was a way to prevent changes to versioned files on SVN. I've already read that there is not.

Comment: @alroc checksums are done only on files with changed timestamp and filesize. If the entire repo was checksumed (every file), that would take hours in many cases. The same with most if not all backup clients.

Comment: But you don't mention that you already did some research :)  ".. no issue viewing the image" really depends on the software you tried with. I.e., a *strict* viewer may reject the image per the specifications. But I'm guessing the closevotes are because you are falling for an [X-Y Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whether appending NULLs is safe or not depends upon the decoding application and library.  If you want to be absolutely safe, insert a private chunk containing the NULLs. Note that this method will always add a minimum of 12 bytes to the file (4-byte length, 4-byte chunk name, zero or more NULL bytes, and a 4-byte CRC), of the form

```
nnnnzpAD000000CRCN
```

where

```
nnnn = number of NULLs
zpAD = chunk name
0000000...  the NULLs
CRCN = 4-byte CRC calculated over the chunk name and the NULLs
```

Put this new "zpAD" chunk (or whatever you decide to call it) just ahead of the existing IEND chunk.

Comment: Thanks - and so this "private" chuck would be like a file that nobody references because of this "zpAD" index?

Comment: Right.  Since it's unpublished, no one knows what it really means (someone might try to reverse engineer it and figure it out though). The private name has to consist only of upper and lower case letters, and should be as I demonstrated: lower, lower, upper, upper.  See the PNG specification for details of what those specific cases mean.  The only danger is that you'll have a name collision with someone else's private chunk that has the same name but different contents.